# What does lawyering mean apart from its official definition

Tags: meaning

The dictionaries define it as "practising law", which is not the case in these examples. I guess its an up-and-coming "new" word which is instantly familiar. What does it mean?

> Language issues.  Combine English as a very second language + 
>   spec-lawyering + late-night meetings, and you have an ongoing
>   headache.

and

> How should I handle an 8 year old lawyering and quibbling?

Comment: The meaning may be litteral - `following law` → taking everything in the very first meaning / having hard time with more figurative sense

Comment: There's also 'lawyering up' which means to start a legal battle by getting some good lawyers. Is that the kind of thing you're thinking of?

Comment: @Edwin: I think the second example could mean "arguing like a lawyer".

Comment: It means "behaving like a lawyer" and may imply any activity stereotypically attributed to lawyers, such as quibbling over petty details, exploiting innocent turns of phrase, chasing ambulances, employing the law courts as an instrument of bullying, and making the worse cause appear the best.

Comment: Shouldn't the second example put in this order? `How should I handle an lawyering and quibbling 8 year old?` Otherwise I would understand the treatment to be lawyering and quibbling. Would that make any sense?

Comment: @Peter You're right. Quibbling about interpretations to get an advantage, rather than pre-empting by imposing the desired legal framework. So this example is tautologous.

Comment: 'Behaving like / as a [_barrack-room_ lawyer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/barrack-room-lawyer)'.

Comment: @Daniel It's a shortened form of _How should I handle an 8 year old who is lawyering and quibbling?_ It's an absolute construction, acceptable for longer adjectivals: _Look at that young lad, happy with his lolly!_ / * _Look at that young lad, happy!_ // _Look at that young lad, exhausted after his race._ / * _Look at that young lad, exhausted!'_  // With _ing_-forms, there seems to be less restriction, at least in colloquial registers: _Did you see the young lad crying?_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I want to thank you for pointing that out. Than this is a question of punctuation. In all your additional examples you added a comma to distinguish the attributes from the sentence. "*Look at that little boy, playing with his toys!*" to "*Look at that little boy, playing!*" I would not object (here referring to -ing forms). The last example does not fit for me: **(to) see *so.* doing *sth.*** is different from `Did you see the crying young lad?` This would be just ***(to) see so*.** even if *so.* is in itself attributed.

Comment: Yes. There are different analyses for different structures. Collins Cobuild lists three 'V + N + ing-form' structures. Here, I'd just say that 'Did you see that child crying?' means 'Did you see that {youngster doing some crying} episode?' whereas 'Did you see the crying child? uses the adjective 'crying' as an identifier. Some _ing_-words cannot be used prenominally (the stealing man).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important part of a professional lawyer's job is looking for inconsistencies and loopholes. This may be *preemptive*, such as determining the exact wording of a contract, or it may be *reactive* ("You didn't actually say that it was required."). In the context of practicing law, this is both expected and laudable. Well, mostly laudable. See the case of Dickens' Jarndyce v Jarndyce https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarndyce_and_Jarndyce, which serves as a classic literary example of the process run amok.

Outside of the law, however, the same process can produce endless discussion of the most minute details and questioning of phrasing ("spec-lawyering" clearly refers to the process of making a specification over-precise or over-broad). It is this situation in which lawyering takes on a universally negative connotation.

A classic (although not legal) example of this focusing on minutiae at the expense of the larger issue is George Tyrell's line: "if the Jesuits were accused of killing three men and a dog, they would invariably produce the dog alive."

Comment: Ya talk like ya know sumpin, Rough Beast. Expected and laudable ... and Jesuit jokes ... very amusing. Keep it up.